# How to trigger angular modal popup on slickgrid row double click

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, row, slickgrid, double-click

I have an angular modal that works with a separate button, but need to have it popup when a row in the slickgrid is double clicked. How should I structure this code:

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  //make the angular modal popup
});
```

With an angular modal, I would normally just select the dom element, then add an ng-click="openModal()" into the div tag but I'm having trouble even locating the div in chrome dev tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have the slickgrid wrapped in a directive, meaning that my html looks like this:

```
<div class="gridContainer" ng-controller="EditModalCtrl">
  <div class="modalTest" style='width:100%;'>
    <div style='width:100%;height:500px;' all-batches-grid></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my slickgrid directive, I have:

```
angular.module('epDefaultApp.allBatchesDirective', [])
  .directive('allBatchesGrid', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link : function(scope, element, attrs){

        grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {

          $('.addButton').removeClass('addText');
          $('#addEditButton').addClass('editButton');
          $('.addButton').addClass('editText');

          var item = grid.getDataItem(args.row);
          scope.openPrefill('lg', item);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Here is my controller as well:

```
angular.module('epDefaultApp.editModalController', [])
  .controller('EditModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'toastr', function     ($scope, $modal, $log, toastr) {

  $scope.openPrefill = function (size, selectedRowObject) {
    $scope.selectedRow = {
      vendorName: selectedRowObject[0],
      purchaseNumber: selectedRowObject[3],
      invoiceAmount: selectedRowObject[6],
      invoiceDate: selectedRowObject[10],
      invoiceNumber: selectedRowObject[1],
      dueDate: selectedRowObject[9],
      checkCode: '0',
      memo: selectedRowObject[5]
    };

}]);
```

The reason that this works is that the scope variable within the directive is actually linked to $scope in the EditModalCtrl. This happens when we first initialize the grid directive in the HTML file.